# Unfortunately, app has stopped

Tags: java, android, manifest

Unfortunately, app has stopped. The purpose of the app is to display a web page when it is launched. I have researched this problem, and tried changing code in the manifest file. I have been unsuccessful at eliminating this message.

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.testb1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;



 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
    Intent getmobilepages = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri =    Uri.parse("http://www.mcohio.org/government/auditor/mobile_app/home.cfm");
    getmobilepages.setData(uri);
    startActivity(getmobilepages);
    }
```

}

testb1 Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.testb1"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
             android:name="com.example.testb1.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.getmobilepages" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Show us the logcat output. It would help if we know what the exception is.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I tried running your code and was completely wrong. You are just missing the line:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

At the start of your oncreate method. Add that in and it should compile just fine.

Make sure to post your logcat in the future, the error is identified clearly there.

Comment: He is still missing the permission and trying to use network on the main thread. There will be runtime exceptions even with the `super` call.

Comment: @StevenByle That was my first impression but I believe since he is starting a generic Action View intent, it just loads up the default browser and shouldn't require permissions. For curiosity sake, I tried running the application without permissions, and it did compile successfuly on my device.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called super you will get SuperNotCalled Exception. You need to set you layout. Better to start another activity on button click.

Add internet permission in manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

MainActivty

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// call  super
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// set your layout 
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
//get button id  
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something
                 Intent getmobilepages = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.mcohio.org/government/auditor/mobile_app/home.cfm");
                 getmobilepages.setData(uri);
                 startActivity(getmobilepages);         
            } 
}); 
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I agree, it would be better to use a button, but the customer wants to go directly to the page, without the button. I got the code to work in the emulator, but when you click on the home button, then the app listing, and then the app. The app opens the layout page, and does not proceed to the web pages.

Comment: then start a browser directly. don't need a activity in between